# Regulated functions

Tags: analysis, functions

Trying this question, would appreciate some help:

Let $\ f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ be a regulated function and fix $\ K \neq 0$ in $\Bbb R$. Define $\ g:[Ka,Kb]\to \Bbb R$ by $\ g(x):=f(x/K)$. Prove that g is a regulated function, and that $\ \int_{Ka}^{Kb} g = K \int_{a}^{b} f$.

As f is regulated, if given $\ \epsilon>0$ there is a sequence of step functions$\ \sigma$ from$\ [a,b] $ such that $\ ||f-\sigma||_\infty<\epsilon$ - to prove g being regulated, are we looking for a similar sequence of step functions, but from $[Ka, Kb]$? Not sure how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathrm{V}, \mathrm{W}$ two normed and complete vector spaces. Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathrm{V}$ be a regulated function. Define $g = f(x)$ and $h = \psi(f)$  where $x:[u, v] \to [a, b]$ is *monotone* and $\psi:\mathrm{V} \to \mathrm{W}$ is *continuous*. Then, $g$ and $h$ are regulated functions (in $\mathrm{V}$ and $\mathrm{W}$).

-Recall: $f$ is regulated is equivalent to saying that $f$ possesses both lateral limits at every point in $(a, b)$ and right limit at $a$ and left limit at $b$-

If $t \uparrow r \in (u, v]$ (resp. $t \downarrow r \in [u, v)$) then $x(t)$ goes *monotonically* to $x(r^-) \in [a, b]$ (resp. $x(r^+) \in [a, v]$), thus $g(t)$ converges to $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to x(r-)^-} f(s)$ if $x$ is increasing or to $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to x(r-)^+} f(s)$ if $x$ is decreasing (resp. to $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to x(r^+)^-} f(s)$ if $x$ is increasing or to $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to x(r^+)^+} f(s)$ if $x$ is decreasing). This proves $g$ is a *reglée* function.

To prove that $h$ is also regulated, notice that when $t \uparrow r \in (a, b]$ (resp. $t \downarrow r \in [a, b)$) then $f(t)$ converges to $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to r^-} f(s)$ (resp. $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to r^+} f(s)$), and by continuity, $h(t)$ will converge to $h$ of the corresponding limit (showing the limit exists). CQFD

To prove your exercise, define $x:[\mathrm{K}a, \mathrm{K}b] \to [a, b]$ by $x(t) = \dfrac{t}{\mathrm{K}}.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider a sequence of functions $\phi_n(x):=\sigma_n(x/K)$ where $\sigma_n$ is a sequence of step functions such that $\Vert f-\sigma_n\Vert _\infty\rightarrow 0$. What can you say about $\phi_n$?